# c# block length does not match with its complement

Tags: c#, memorystream

I am stuck with this error and I don't understand why. Can you help me out? I am trying to edit a PowerPoint file on a Sharepoint through the Client Object Model and OpenXML. The editing is working fine but for some reason I get thrown the `block length does not match with its complement`Error. I have not yet found anything on google that helped.

Here is the Code in question:

```
class Program
{
    // Credentials to log into the Sharepoint.
    private static NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("login", "pwd", "domain");
    static private void CopyStream(Stream source, Stream destination)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        int bytesRead;
        do
        {
            bytesRead = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            destination.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        } while (bytesRead != 0);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Creating the Clientcontext
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://sharepoint.adress.com/folder/");
            clientContext.Credentials = credential;
            Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;

            // Collect all lists from Sharepoint.
            ListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists;
            clientContext.Load(collList);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to Sharepoint.");

            // Getting the Presentation.
            Console.WriteLine("Working on " + filename + "..");
            Guid id = new Guid("2BBF9030-66C6-4F71-86E6-DFE41F57B9F3"); // List ID for the Slide Library.
            List sharedDocumentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(id);
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            String queryString = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type='Text'>" + filename + 
                "</Value></Eq></Where><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></Query></View>";    // FileLeafRef is the column "name" on the Sharepoint.
            camlQuery.ViewXml = @queryString;
            ListItemCollection listItems = sharedDocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.Credentials = credential;
            clientContext.Load(sharedDocumentsList);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            clientContext.Credentials = credential;
            clientContext.Load(listItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("Opened Document.");



            if (listItems.Count == 1)
            {
                ListItem item = listItems[0];
                clientContext.Credentials = credential;
                FileInformation fileInformation = ClientOM.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, (string)item["FileRef"]);

                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    CopyStream(fileInformation.Stream, memoryStream);

                    using (PresentationDocument ppt = PresentationDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
                    {
                        string rId = GetSlidePart(ppt, slideNumber - 1);
                        PresentationPart pptPart = ppt.PresentationPart;
                        SlidePart slide = (SlidePart)pptPart.GetPartById(rId);
                        Boolean exists = false;

                        //groupExists(slide.Slide, "IDGroup", exists);

                        if (!groupExists(slide.Slide, "IDGroup", exists))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(exists);
                            Console.WriteLine("IDGroup not found in " + filename + ", adding it..");
                            EditPresentation(memoryStream, clientContext, item);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(exists);
                            Console.WriteLine("IDGroup already exists, skipping Presentation..");
                        }
                    } // Error gets thrown here.
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Document not found.");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.Read();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (ex is ServerException || ex is InvalidCastException || ex is OpenXmlPackageException || ex is WebException)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            Console.Read();

        }
}
```

And this is the Method that edits the File. Trimmed to the parts where I use the memoryStream, the full code can be viewed [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4nHCRwi7):

```
public static void EditPresentation(MemoryStream memoryStream, ClientContext clientContext, ListItem item)
{
    using (PresentationDocument ppt = PresentationDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
    {
        string rId = GetSlidePart(ppt, slideNumber - 1);
        PresentationPart pptPart = ppt.PresentationPart;
        SlidePart slide = (SlidePart)pptPart.GetPartById(rId);
        ShapeTree tree = new ShapeTree();
        CommonSlideData commonSlideData1 = new CommonSlideData();

        // 250 Lines of OpenXML go here.

        slide.AddHyperlinkRelationship(new System.Uri(adress, System.UriKind.Absolute), true, "rId99");
        slide.Slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.Append(groupShape1);
        slide.Slide.Save();
        pptPart.Presentation.Save();
    }

    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    ClientOM.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, (string)item["FileRef"], memoryStream, true);
}
```

Is there something fundamental I am doing wrong? I've never done anything like this and as always all suggestions for improvements would be appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that you need to set the memoryStream.Position to 0 before you open the open the presentationdocument?

Comment: Do you mean by adding `memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`? I already added that in the line before the exception is thrown. It didn't change anything.

Comment: Try replacing the call to your `CopyStream` method with `fileInformation.Stream.CopyTo(memoryStream)`.

Comment: Sadly `Stream.CopyTo`did not change anything. Still the same error.

Comment: You should put the Seek directly after `CopyStream(fileInformation.Stream, memoryStream);`

Comment: Why are you opening the Presentationdocument again in EditPresentation? just use the PresentationDcument as an argument ...

Comment: Try skipping to first two bytes when copying the stream from `fileInformation` to memory.

Comment: @Jocie I already tried that, sadly no luck.

Comment: @rene That got rid of the error, but now the presentation I am editing is corrupted.. I'll try to find out why.

Comment: Try downloading and editing it manually, the file might actually be corrupted. (Probably not, but it's worth eliminating as a possibility)

Comment: The presentation I am editing is an empty Slide which I am reuploading for each test. No problems editing it locally. Interestingly enough, the editing through my programm is fine as long as the exception is thrown. But I am not doing anything with the presentation anymore at the point were it was.